# Selective 'upwards' SVN checkout

Tags: svn

Maybe I misunderstood how depth works in SVN, but I think it looks either down the tree (to children) or sideways (to siblings). I'd like to know if it's possible to 'look up the tree', i.e. check out a parent, grandparent, great-grandparent, etc of an item. For example, say my remote repo has the following structure:

```
remote_root
   dir_1
      dir_3
         file_1
      dir_4
         file_2
         file_3
   dir_2
```

And I am interested only in `file_2` right now. I'd love to be able to go into a local and empty directory, say `local_root`, and, with a single command, end up with no more and no less than:

```
local_root
   dir_1
      dir_4
         file_2
```

Is this possible? If yes, how?